# Printer / PaperSize java

Tags: java, printing, format

I would like to have a list of paper sizes for my web application.
I need also a paper size for 6x4. Please see below:

[image]

I found the following list, but I can´t find this page format:
http://files.idrsolutions.com/samplecode/org/jpedal/examples/viewer/paper/PaperSizes.java.html

Any ideas?
How can I get all existing page formats?

Answer (score 0):

Does this class works for you , [MediaSizeName](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/print/attribute/standard/MediaSizeName.html)?  Also, it looks that 6*4 is a custom size ( not an ISO standard ) so that value is not available in that class. Can you show your sample code?

I think, you need to convert your size from absolute inches to pixels per inch format  and then set that size in your Paper class. Usually, print API has 72 as DPI ( Dots Per Inch ) so you might like to convert dimensions as `double length = 6*72d;` and `double width = 4*72d;` and then you can set that size in your code.

Hope it helps !!

Comment: can´t find there 6x4 ? Any ideas?

Comment: I have edited my answer with updated information. let me know if that helps